# how to refresh wpf elementhost inside winform

Tags: c#, wpf

When my usercontrol(WindowScreen) loads for the first time, my elementhost displays correctly. When I instantiate the usercontrol and pass in a different id, the elementhost doesnt get updated. Is there a reason why for this or is there a way to fix this?

Here's my code.

WindowScreen.cs -- winform:

```
public partial class WindowScreen : UserControl
{
    private WindowView _windowView;
    private WindowViewModel _windowViewModel = null;

    public WindowScreen(int id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        elementHost.Child = this.elementHost1;
        _windowViewModel = new WindowViewModel();
        _windowView = (WindowView) this.elementHost.Child;
        //_windowViewModel.LoadTypes(123); --- first load
                  _windowViewModel.LoadTypes(id); --- pass in parameter
        _windowView.DataContext = _windowViewModel;
    }
}
```

TestScreen.cs -- winform:

```
public partial class TestScreen : UserControl
{
    public TestScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowScreen ws = new WindowScreen(298);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this:

```
WindowScreen ws = new WindowScreen(298);
```

You're creating a new `WindowScreen`, but never setting it to be used in your `TestScreen` control.  You need to overwrite the current `WindowScreen` with this one - something like:

```
// This needs to be the appropriate/correct variable
this.windowScreen1 = new WindowScreen(298);
```

Comment: I've tried what you said by doing this.windowScreen = new WindowScreen(298); but to no avail. So when I click the button in the Test usercontrol, I'm going to pass a parameter to the WindowScreen usercontrol (which has an elementhost), this is suppose to update the elementhost in the WindowScreen. My elementhost(WindowView) still isnt updating. Any other suggestion?